# Summing up a related table's values in PowerPivot/DAX

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Say I have two tables. attrsTable:

```
file | attribute | value
------------------------
A    | xdim      | 5
A    | ydim      | 6
B    | xdim      | 7
B    | ydim      | 3
B    | zdim      | 2
C    | xdim      | 1
C    | ydim      | 7
```

sizeTable:

```
file | size
-----------
A    | 17
B    | 23
C    | 34
```

I have these tables related via the 'file' field. I want a PowerPivot measure within attrsTable, whose calculation uses size. For example, let's say I want xdim+ydim/size for each of A, B, C. The calculations would be:

```
A: (5+6)/17
B: (7+3)/23
C: (1+7)/34
```

I want the measure to be generic enough so I can use slicers later on to slice by file or attribute. How do I accomplish this?

I tried:

```
dimPerSize := CALCULATE([value]/SUM(sizeTable[size])) # Calculates 0
dimPerSize := CALCULATE([value]/SUM(RELATED(sizeTable[size]))) # Produces an error
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm probably missing some fundamental concepts here of how to use DAX with relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Redstreet,**

taking a step back from your solution and the one proposed by Jacob, I think it might be useful to create another table that would aggregate all the calculations (especially given you probably have more than 2 tables with file-specific attributes).

So I have created one more table that contains (only) unique file names, and thus the relationships could be visualized this way:

[image]

It's much simpler to add necessary measures (no need for calculated columns). I have actually tested 2 scenarios:

1) create simple SUM measures for both *Attribute Value* and *File Size*. Then divide those two measures and **job done** :-).

2) use SUMX functions to have a bit more universal solution. Then the final formula for *DimPerSize* calculation could look like this:

```
=DIVIDE(
   SUMX(DISTINCT(fileTable[file]),[Sum of AttrValue]), 
   SUMX(DISTINCT(fileTable[file]),[Sum of FileSize]), 
   BLANK()
)
```

With [Sum of AttrValue] being:

```
=SUM(attrsTable[value])
```

And Sum of FileSize being:

```
=SUM(sizeTable[size])
```

This worked perfectly fine, even though SUMX in both cases goes over all instances of given file name. So for file *B* it also calculates with *zdim* (if there is a need to filter this out, then use simple calculate / filter combination). In case of file size, I am using SUMX as well, even though it's not really needed since the table contains **only 1 record for each file name**. If there would be 2 instances, then use SUMX or AVERAGEX depending on the desired outcome.

[This is the link to my source file in Excel (2010).](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgje2wznym0ivco/answer.xlsx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You look to have the concept of relationships OK but you aren't on the right track in terms of CALCULATE() either in terms of the structure or the fact that you can't simply use 'naked' numerical columns, they need to be packaged in some way.

Your desired approach is correct in that once you get a simple version of the thing running, you will be able to slice and dice it over any of your related dimensions.

Best practice is probably to build this up using several measures:

```
[xdim] = CALCULATE(SUM('attrstable'[value]), 'attrstable'[attribute] = "xdim")
[ydim] = CALCULATE(SUM('attrstable'[value]), 'attrstable'[attribute] = "ydim")
[dimPerSize] = ([xdim] + [ydim]) / VALUES('sizeTable'[size])
```

But depending on exactly how your pivot is set up, this is likely to also throw an error because it will try and use the whole 'size' column in your totals. There are two main strategies for dealing with this:

1. Use an 'iterative' formula such as SUX() or AVERAGEX() to iterate individually over the 'file' field and then adds up or averages for the total e.g.

   [ItdimPerSize] = AVERAGEX(VALUES('sizeTable'[file]), [dimPerSize])

   Depending on the maths you want to use, you might find that produce a useful average that you need to use SUMX but devide by the number of cases i.e. COUNTROWS('sizeTable'[file]).
2. You might decide that the totals are irrelevant and simply introduce an error handling element that will make them blank e.g.

   [NtdimPerSize] = IF(HASONEVALUE('sizeTable'[file]),[dimPerSize],BLANK())

NB, all of this assumes that when you are creating your pivot that you are 'dragging in' the file field from the 'sizetable'.

Comment: thanks for the response, but there seem to be several problems with what you've outlined. a) syntax: I assume you mean ydim:=..., and not [ydim]=... b) your [dimPerSize] divides by VALUES(). VALUES() returns a table, and thus, I get an error; c) I can't filter by "xdim", "ydim", etc. because there are too many of them, and also, I want to slice by them later d) because of (b), your formulas in 1. and 2. don't work. Any pointers?

Comment: Don't get the point you are trying to make with a) - there is no universal convention about how portray that something is a Dax measure and it certainly isn't a syntax error. The text in the [] is the measure name and everything to the right is the body of the measure. In terms of b) and consequently d) I simply suggest you read the whole answer has half of it is about ways to use VALUES() but deal with the fact that the formula expects a single value. You might need to provide a fuller explanation of your desired outputs.

Comment: With a), it seems like x := ... is the exact syntax one types in into the calculated field (aka measure). I guess your use of [x]=... instead, and the fact that your DAX returns a table confused me. With b) and d), I did read, but am still not sure I understand your approach: you seem to be suggesting using two measures (dimPerSize and ItdimPerSize for eg), where the second depends on the first. the first is not a valid measure, and I'm not able to get it to work even using an aggregation function.

Comment: Reducing the problem: as a first step, how do I create a measure in attrsTable which sums sizeTable[size] with the current context?

Comment: Aslo, with a), I'm new to PowerPivot, so I'm not used to the conventions yet, sorry! Just to make sure I'm on the same page, I'm typing these expressions into empty cells in the calculated fields area in the PowerPivot table. Please let me know if I'm not on the right track.